# IIS10 wildcard domain - is that normal?

Tags: iis, wildcards, subdomain

Is it normal, that when I have such binding: *.domain.com I can only use subdomain1.domain.com, subdomain2.domain.com etc, but when I type let say a.b.c.domain.com the IIS takes me to (literally!) an unknown website? I know it's bizarre, but true. I tried to investigate that, and, for example I stopped all the application pools one by one, and even having them all stopped the strange, unknown website was still on! Only stopping the whole IIS resulted in stopping that website too. There was only standard 404 displayed.

Maybe I am wrong, but I think, that multiple level subdomains were working fine when I had that server freshly installed... Can't remember now.

Anyway, it doesn't work with multiple level subdomains and I have to use separate dedicated IP to have it working as I want.

Is there anything I can do to fix that problem or is it just the way IIS10 works?

Comment: Perhaps the wildcard only matches one level at a time. Have you tried `*.*.example.com` as a wildcard hostname?

Comment: Yes. That is an illegal option. You can't do that. It is really strange, it should take anything after the first dot. And that mystery website...